# Using a static method in a class where you need an instance of that class

Tags: java

I would like to make the ODE_solver static so that I model multiple ODE systems without creating an instance of the solver class each time. I would like to call the solver within the ODEsystem object. is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Static Class:

```
public class ODE_solver {
   public static double[] solveODE(ODESystem eqn, double time, double delta) { 
    // does computation
   }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ODESystem {
    int getSystemSize();
    double[] getCurrentValues();
    double[] getFunction(double time, double[] values);
} // end ODESystem interface
```

How I'm trying to access the current object:

```
public class Star implements ODESystem {
    // constants & variables
    // methods required by the interface
    public double[] getPosition(double time, double delta){ 
        return solveODE(this.ODESystem, time, delta);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ODE_Solver.solveODE(this, time, delta)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the method is a `static` member of `ODE_solver`, call it on this class:

```
return ODE_solver.solveODE(this.ODESystem, time, delta);
```

Comment: Also remember to import the solver class in your Star class to access the method